# Console hosted WCF service terminated unexpectedly without any tracelog

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have three project cobol (backend) and wcf service (communicator) and asp.net web application(client) .

I hosted the wcf services in console application using windows services . when client send a request it will be passed via service to backend and response from backend to client via service
here comes the issue :

if some error occurs in the backend (cobol)during the processing of request then wcf service hosted in console gets terminated  abruptly without any trace. But client gets an exception:

> `an error occured while recieving the http response to http://localhost:8081/testclient. this could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the http protocol.this could also be due to an http request context being aborted by the server(possibly due to the service shutting down ).see server logs for more details`.

When i checked the Trace log of host there is log till the processing in Back-end but no details about the host console termination

this is my app.config of client  `

```
<basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Itestclient" openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8081/testclient" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Itestclient" contract="SvcReftestclient.Itestclient"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_Itestclient" />
</client>
```

`

increased the maxReceivedMessageSize too but no use,

this is my config for host for trace log

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel"
              switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
              propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="traceListener"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
              initializeData= "D:\testclient\Trace\Traces.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

How to capture such error in trace?  How to prevent the host console from termination on such condition?

Comment: What is the `innerexception` on the client?

Comment: I would like to suggest try catch for all methods (or implement IOperationInvoker to add try catch for every web service method at once). Actually backend failure should not cause wcf service to be terminated.

Comment: i have included try catch for all methods in both client and services , it catches the exception if an exception thrown . but some extinct backend throws a error which terminates the service .how to handle such situation . it will be fine service termination is prevented

Comment: I suggest you try use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see what was sen/received over the wire.

Comment: thanks for your reply @oleksa and vitor Canova .i found my issue for that , one of my table in the backend program was missing it throwed an error which was not handled properly ... now its working fine